# Editing immediately after click the "edit" link, I see the edited content disappearing

Tags: support, bug, edits

When I click the edit link of a post, then type immediately, then, after a few seconds, the post will return to the state before edited. I have to type again.

This may be caused by the network latency, but could this problem be solved?

It will happen when you click the edit link multiple times quickly, and edit immediately after the textarea shows.

Check [this link](http://www.shareswf.com/game/26814/stackoverflow-editting-issues), I recorded my screen.

Comment: `then after a few seconds, the post will return to the state before edited`. But how? By clicking `Save Edit`, `Cancel`, back button of browser or automatic?

Comment: @hims056 Automatic....

Comment: @kiamlaluno The edited part disappears after a few seconds, that's what I mean.

Comment: Does this always happens or just in some cases? If so, describe what you do.

Comment: I think you need to describe your question more briefly, i can not figure out what you want to ask.

Comment: Cannot replicate. I clicked edit and immediately started typing (even before page loaded, and the post is edited the moment the focus moves to the textarea) then waited a few minutes... edited content remains. (Firefox 15.0.1)

Comment: Wait some time, i will try to make a gif to show it.

Comment: @xdazz Yes this occurs to me also. But not every time. Does [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148690/187824) occurs to you after canceling it without editing?

Comment: @hims056 Yes, this occurs to me very often, I need to wait some time then edit. it happens when you double click the edit link .