# Bug when editing and canceling a post

Tags: bug, edits

Look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148684/187824). I was trying to replicate the issue. But while doing that I found a new bug!

I suspect this issue occur only for 2K+ users.
The issue is:

As we know when we click on edit link of any post, it does not redirect to new page (for 2K+ users only). But when we click more than one time immediately before text-area is shown (as more as we can click), then cancel it. You will see the *text-areas* (Yes **s**) of edit remain there more than once.

[Look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZqcj.png)

These text-areas are increased if we again click (more than once) on edit at this situation and cancel it!

I tried it in Chrome, IE, Mozilla and Opera. This occurs in all of these browsers.

Comment: Do you have a user script running? or some extensions? It seems you in particular end up calling our `.init()` functions multiple times which shouldn't happen with the vanilla page.  Seeing as this is a repeated issue with multiple functions in different contexts that we've *never* had reported before (or any recent changes to), I'm very inclined to believe something out of the ordinary is running in your browser.

Comment: @NickCraver I am using Chrome. There are only two external extensions 1) Awesome Screenshot and 2) Norton's Site Safety. Wait I try with Mozilla or I.E.

Comment: @NickCraver It's strange. But also I tried it in I.E., Mozilla and Opera. It occurs there also.

Comment: @NickCraver - I can actually repoduce this on FF 15.0.1 (only with Firebug). It's not *always* the case for me but double-clicking on the edit link and then cancelling it often produces multiple edit toolbars.

Comment: @NickCraver - Looks like the issue is resolved. Tested on Chrome, FF. :)